# mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in using PHP. I made something simple to connect to MySQL and select a database:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_admin, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
// these variables are previously declared and initialized 

$selected_db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

When I tested it, I got a successfully-established connection and the following warning:

```
mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given
```

Why did this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using both `mysqli` and `mysql` simply change

`mysql_select_db()`

With

```
mysqli_select_db
```

**Reference** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

`updated`

When you use `mysql_select_db` you are supposed to use `mysql` api and so you have to exatibilish connection to database with mysql sintax `mysql_connect` [Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Mysql is now deprecated so it's correct either to use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: yeah that was the mistake :) thank you , can u explain the difference please :) ?

Comment: They are two different APIs for communication with mysql. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use the `mysqli_*` ones.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using mysqli_* consistently (as mentioned in [Fabio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16002365/899126)), there is an additional problem (and a suggestion):

- While the parameter order in `mysql_select_database` are database name, connection, the order of parameters in [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) are connection, database name.

  ```
  mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name);
  ```
- As a suggestion, [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) includes an optional fourth parameter to connect to a particular database. This would allow you to avoid calling `mysql_select_db` altogether.

  ```
  $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_admin, $db_pass, $db_name)
      or die(mysqli_connect_error());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `mysql_select_db` to `mysqli_select_db` as pointed out by `Fabio` but you'll get an error

```
mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
```

For someone experiencing this, reverse the order of parameters, like for in this case give

```
$selected_db = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)
```